# 404 error when deploying django project with apache2

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache2, mod-wsgi

I tried to create a new django project on apache2, but I got 404 error.
Here are what I did.

-In /home/ubuntu/django directory, type

```
django-admin startproject proj
```

-Edit proj/proj/wsgi.py as follows.

```
import os
import sys


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/django/proj');
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/django/proj/proj');

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

-Edit ALLOWED_HOSTS in proj/proj/settings.py as follows.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com']
```

-Edit /etc/apache2/conf-available/wsgi.conf as follows.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /proj /home/ubuntu/django/proj/proj/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/django/proj

<Directory /home/ubuntu>
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/proj/proj>
 <Files wsgi.py>
  Require all granted
 </Files>
</Directory>
```

-Restart apache2 as

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

-Access to http://example.com/proj, and then got 404 error as follows.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://example.com/proj/
Using the URLconf defined in proj.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

My enviroment is as follows.

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (AWS)
- Apache/2.4.29
- Python 3.6.9
- Django 3.0.5

How can I solve this 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have '/admin' in your urls.py file?
You may also need to change the apache2 settings from /home/ubuntu/proj/proj to  /home/ubuntu/django/proj/proj

Comment: I fixed the path in /etc/apache2/conf-available/wsgi.conf, but the result is same.

Also, urls.py has a entry, path('admin/', admin.site.urls).

Comment: You are requesting /proj/ url which doesn’t exists hence the 404. For admin you should request the /admin url

Comment: I do not understand. I request /proj, because that is my project, not /admin. You mean it is not enough to edit /etc/apache2/conf-available/wsgi.conf? Then, how can I register /proj to remove 404 error?

Comment: a 404 error just means that the url you are requesting was not found( probably if its not defined in your urls.py file). What does your  /home/ubuntu/django/proj/proj/urls.py file look like? from the response above , i think you only have the /admin url defined but nothing else.